# JasperReports won't replace $R{} when internationalizing report

Tags: internationalization, jasper-reports

I need to produce i18n reports with existing code using JasperReports (4.7.1 originally but same problem with 5.6.1).
I did the following:

1. Report name is: x_report.jrxml
2. Added attribute resourceBundle="x_report" to the jasperReport tag in the jrxml file
3. Replaced text with $R{} tags in jrxml file
4. Built file

Added JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE and JRParameter.REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE to the parameters to pass to the JasperFillManager:

```
    File reportFile = new File(getClass().getResource("/reports").getFile(), report.getReportFileName());
    Map<String, Object> fillParams = (Map<String, Object>) report.getFillParameters();
    java.util.Locale locale = new java.util.Locale("it");
    fillParams.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, locale);
    String resBundleName = ...
    ResourceBundle resBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(resBundleName, locale);
    fillParams.put(JRParameter.REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE, resBundle);
    ...
```

The JasperFillManager getting the params (with locale and resource bundle) and the report path:

```
    BeanReport report = (BeanReport) this.report;
    Collection<?> beans = report.getBeans();
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(beans);
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportFile.getPath(), fillParams, ds);
    ...

    if (httpSession != null) {
        httpSession.setAttribute(ImageServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, print);
        exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI, "ReportImage?image=");
    }
```

exporter is a JRExporter:

```
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    exporter.exportReport();
```

The resource bundle is found but my generated report still has the $R{} tags instead of the localized text.

What could be missing?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you maybe using labels instead of text fields?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using JasperReports Server or not, but if you are what worked for me was to drop my properties bundle files into the ../jasperserver-pro/WEB-INF/classes folder.